# How would I parse this JSON, looks like an array but no "[]"s

Tags: json, spring, jackson, resttemplate

I'm using Springboot with RestTemplate to parse JSON. All the resources i'm looking at deal with arrays, but I understand that arrays need brackets ([]).

I have JSON here (https://rsbuddy.com/exchange/summary.json)

(short example in case link goes down)

```
    {"2": {"overall_average": 216, "sp": 5, "members": true, "buy_average": 215,
 "sell_average": 215, "name": "Cannonball", "id": 2}, "6": {"overall_average":
 173518, "sp": 187500, "members": true, "buy_average": 190176, "sell_average": 
189343, "name": "Cannon base", "id": 6}, ... , 

"12287": {"overall_average": 0,
     "sp": 5200, "members": false, "buy_average": 3234, "sell_average": 3234, 
    "name": "Mithril platebody (t)", "id": 12287}}
```

that feels like it should be an array because it's a list, but it doesn't have brackets, and can't be parsed with the following code:

```
public List<ItemSummaryContainer> consumeItems() {

        ResponseEntity<List<ItemSummaryContainer>> itemSummaryResponse =
                restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<ItemSummaryContainer>>() {

                });

        return itemSummaryResponse.getBody();
    }
```

ItemSummaryContainer class

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ItemSummaryContainer {

    private int id;
    private ItemSummary itemSummary;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public ItemSummary getItemSummary() {
        return itemSummary;
    }
    public void setItemSummary(ItemSummary itemSummary) {
        this.itemSummary = itemSummary;
    }   
}
```

ItemSummary class

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ItemSummary {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Integer members;

    public ItemSummary() {

    }
    public ItemSummary(Integer id, String name, Integer members) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.members = members;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getMembers() {
        return members;
    }
    public void setMembers(int members) {
        this.members = members;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        ItemSummary other = (ItemSummary) obj;
        if (id != other.id)
            return false;
        if (members != other.members)
            return false;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        return true;
    }   
}
```

Stacktrace

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:801) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:782) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:769) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at com.tjwhalen.game.Application.main(Application.java:50) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@55f8669d; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@55f8669d; line: 1, column: 1]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:228) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:213) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:95) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:884) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:868) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:622) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:580) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:526) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at com.tjwhalen.game.service.dao.ItemSummaryURLConsumer.consumeItems(ItemSummaryURLConsumer.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.tjwhalen.game.service.impl.ItemSummaryRestServiceImpl.getItems(ItemSummaryRestServiceImpl.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.tjwhalen.game.loader.LoadItems.load(LoadItems.java:38) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.tjwhalen.game.loader.LoaderRunner.execute(LoaderRunner.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.tjwhalen.game.Application$AppConfig.run(Application.java:78) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:798) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@55f8669d; line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:261) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.1.jar:2.8.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportMappingException(DeserializationContext.java:1233) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.1.jar:2.8.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1121) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.1.jar:2.8.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1074) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.1.jar:2.8.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.handleNonArray(CollectionDeserializer.java:328) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.1.jar:2.8.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:259) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.1.jar:2.8.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:249) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.1.jar:2.8.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:26) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.1.jar:2.8.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3789) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.1.jar:2.8.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2913) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.1.jar:2.8.1]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:225) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Please advise, or ask any needed clarifying questions,

Thanks

Comment: You should include a sample JSON in the question instead of linking to the actual file. As it currently stands, if the link becomes dead the question will become completely incomprehensible to future visitors.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll do that when I get home today, it's really long so I was thinking something like {"2":{...}, "6":{...}, ......} so I could show a significant amount of samples but not paste the whole thing, or should I paste the whole thing?

Comment: Just a representative part of it will be fine, enough to understand the question. 2 entries and then some dots as you thought would be just fine. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON you are trying to parse is perfectly valid. It's not an array, but it's still valid:

```json
{
  "2": {
    "overall_average": 211,
    "buy_average": 208,
    "members": true,
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Cannonball",
    "sell_average": 210,
    "sp": 5
  },
  "6": {
    "overall_average": 0,
    "buy_average": 0,
    "members": true,
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Cannon base",
    "sell_average": 0,
    "sp": 187500
  },
  "12289": {
    "overall_average": 9999,
    "buy_average": 0,
    "members": false,
    "id": 12289,
    "name": "Mithril platelegs (t)",
    "sell_average": 9999,
    "sp": 2600
  },
  ...
}
```

The `ItemSummary` class could be defined as following:

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ItemSummary {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private boolean members;

    // Getters and setters omitted
}
```

And the whole JSON could be parsed into a `Map<String, ItemSummary>`. See the details below.

### Parsing the JSON into a `Map<String, ItemSummary>`

With Spring REST Template, use:

```java
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(); 
ResponseEntity<Map<String, ItemSummary>> response = 
        restTemplate.exchange(
            "https://rsbuddy.com/exchange/summary.json", 
            HttpMethod.GET, 
            null, 
            new ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, ItemSummary>>() {});

Map<String, ItemSummary> map = response.getBody();
```

With Jackson's [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html), you could have:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, ItemSummary> map = 
    mapper.readValue(new URL("https://rsbuddy.com/exchange/summary.json"),
                     new TypeReference<Map<String, ItemSummary>>() {});
```

### Wrapping the `Map<String, ItemSummary>` into a class

If you need a wrapper class around the `Map<String, ItemSummary>`, define it as following:

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ItemSummaryContainer {

    private Map<String, ItemSummary> items;

    @JsonCreator
    public ItemSummaryContainer(Map<String, ItemSummary> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    // Getters and setters omitted
}
```

With Spring REST Template, use:

```java
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(); 
ResponseEntity<ItemSummaryContainer> response = 
    restTemplate.exchange(
        "https://rsbuddy.com/exchange/summary.json", 
        HttpMethod.GET, 
        null, 
        new ParameterizedTypeReference<ItemSummaryContainer>() {});

ItemSummaryContainer container = response.getBody();
```

And with Jackson's [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html), you would have:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ItemSummaryContainer container = 
    mapper.readValue(new URL("https://rsbuddy.com/exchange/summary.json"),
                     ItemSummaryContainer.class);
```

Comment: Thanks guys! This is my first project working with JSON so I'm really new to it and didn't think to map it to a map, excellent examples!

Comment: @TylerWhalen I'm happy to know my answer was useful :)

Answer (score 1):

It's mismatch between JSON and the JAVA class.

Which is in your scope ? JSON or Java ? Fix either of these and according to Json change Java class or vice versa.

Your JSON:

```
{
"2" : {
    "members" : true,
    "sell_average" : 207,
    "id" : 2,
    "buy_average" : 206,
    "sp" : 5,
    "name" : "Cannonball",
    "overall_average" : 209
},
"6" : {
    "members
.....
```

As per this it is expecting a `Java object` as in your description and not `LIST`.

When you cannot change JSON input, match your java class to be

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ItemSummaryContainer {

    private Map<Integer,  ItemSummary> items;
    // getter and setter
}
```

If it is other side, change your JSON.