# Spring Rest template trying to parse JSON Response and model it in form of getters and setters

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I have following json to parse in spring rest template.I could not see how I could do it.I have never seen such a json, but this is a valid json response.
THis is what I have tried :

```
 @jsonignoreuknown(true)
class smsresponse { 

    private String status;
    private String message;
    private Data data;
    getters/setters

    }

    class Data {

    private String group_id;
    private Map<String,SummaryPOJO> map;
    getters/setters

    }

    class SummaryPOJO {

    private String id;
    private String mobile;
    private String status;
    rest of fields
    getteers/setters

    }

restTemplate.exchange(url,method,null,some paramterhere)
```

Is it right approach and what rest template API should I call to achieve this.

```
 {
        "status": "OK",
        "data": 
        {
            "group_id":zzz,
            "0":
            {
                "id": "wewew-1wewewew",
                "customid": "1",
                "customid1": "",
                "customid2": "",
                "mobile": "9190********",
                "status": "AWAITED-DLR",
                }         
               "1":
                {
                "id": "2758-2",
                "customid": "2",
                "customid1": "",
                "customid2": "",
                "mobile": "9190********",
                "status": "AWAITED-DLR",
                }            
              }
                ...
        }
        "message": "Campaign Submitted successfully"
    }
```

Comment: What do you meant by this `parse in spring rest template` ? Are you callling some REST API from which you are getting the above response?

Comment: Yes that is what i meant.Parse in this context stands for parsing of json through rest template.I am calling a third party rest api and this is json structure they have.We heavily leverage rest template for consuming services.I am looking if someone already has implemented this structure in json.

Comment: Update:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39462204/how-would-i-parse-this-json-looks-like-an-array-but-no-s/39465823#39465823                               Above link has partial solution to what I am looking for.But my json structure has some top level attr which are also needed.Let us see ,other wise I have to implement custom solution for this

Answer (score 0):

If you use spring boot RestTemplate with for example maven you automatically have jackson as dependency which maps your response object without any further code. Calling it correctly and specifying your expected class `smsresponse` and jackson will map it for you. It's much easier to use the methods `restTemplate.getForObject(...)` or `restTemplate.postForObject(...)` instead of `restTemplate.exchange(...)` for GET and POST but that highly depends on your needs. This methods have some limitations regarding setting headers and so on.

The spring documentation provides plenty of good examples:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html

Comment: that is what my intention is.I have earlier used this template sucessfully to map a number of different  json response back to POJOs.Question here is not about using template ,but how to model response on client side to as per json response.That is why I posted the json.I was looking if someone has done something similar .Idea is to model coming json response in form of classes and that is what I am looking for.Thanks for your answer btw

Comment: Since you would like to define your response as a class your approach seems fine to me.If the service provides some schema files you could think about using the schema files and generate the POJOs out of it. Same discussion if the service provides swagger definition. I would go for genrating my POJOs if such defintions are available, provides you more stability using it that way and you will be also more flexible to interface changes.

Comment: we don't have access to any schema files so that is out of window.I could not get much success in modeling the class.So I ended up collecting response in a map and built my own response rather than jackson doing it class.It is kinda crude,but for time being it serves the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

**This answer might not be suitable for all,but it serves my purpose for time being.**

```
 public SmsResponse sendSMS(String recipient, String dynamicMessage) throws Exception {
    String message = URLEncoder.encode(dynamicMessage, "UTF-8");
    String requestUrl = MessageFormat.format(getApiEndPoint(), recipient, message);

    System.out.println("Printing request url from property message" + requestUrl);
    Map<String, Object> smsResponse = getRestTemplate().getForObject(requestUrl, Map.class);
    return createSMSResponseClass(smsResponse);

  }

  private SmsResponse createSMSResponseClass(Map<String, Object> map) {
    SmsResponse smsResponse = new SmsResponse();
    if (map.containsKey("status")) {
      smsResponse.setStatus((String) map.get("status"));
    }
    if (map.containsKey("message")) {
      smsResponse.setMessage((String) map.get("message"));
    }
    if (map.containsKey("data")) {
      Map<String, Object> data = (Map<String, Object>) map.get("data");
      if (data.containsKey("group_id")) {
        smsResponse.setGroupId((String) map.get("group_id"));
}
        if (data.containsKey("0")) {
          Map<String, Object> metaData = (Map<String, Object>) data.get("0");
          ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
          SMSMetaDataObject smsMetaDataObject =
              mapper.convertValue(metaData, SMSMetaDataObject.class);
          smsResponse.setSmsMetaDataObject(smsMetaDataObject);

        }

    }
    logger.info(String.format("Printing sms response object %s", smsResponse.toString()));
    return smsResponse;

  }
```